# CCNode addChild from method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccnode

I am trying to add a CCNode to my scene.

It works using this in the scene class (Level.m) itself:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    CCLOG(@"didLoadFromCCB");
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

     CCNode *node = [CCBReader load:@"NodeClassName"];

     node.position = ccp(10 , 54);

     [self addChild:node];
}
```

now I am trying to do the same thing but now by calling a method of another class (Cursor.m) which looks like this:

```
-(void) place: (int) yPos{


    CCNode * node = [CCBReader load:@"NodeClassName"];

    node.position = ccp(10 , yPos);

    [self addChild:node];


    NSLog(@"placed");

}
```

Level.m:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    CCLOG(@"didLoadFromCCB");
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    Cursor *co = [[Cursor alloc] init];
    [co place: 54];
}
```

why is this not working?

Comment: "not working" meaning what exactly?

Comment: the node just doesn't show up.

Comment: what about the log, is it printed to the console or not?

Comment: Yes, the log says "placed".

Comment: Check the "position" (bad name) parameter and Cursor.ccb node positions then, perhaps they're simply outside the screen.

Comment: still doesn't work if I use `node.position = ccp(10 , 54);` instead of `node.position = ccp(10 , position);`

Comment: Do I have to declare on what scene the node is supposed to be placed on, since its not inside the same class anymore?

Comment: Depends on what "self" is and where or whether it's been added as child to the scene in the first place.

Comment: there's a [self addChild:co] missing

Comment: true… is there a way to do it from inside the `Cursor.m` ?